# Teradata: how to get greatest DATE in a row?

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, teradata

I'm trying to get maximum date in a row. Both fuctions, `MAX` and `Greatest` return errors:

```
SEL Max(date1,date2,date3...)
SELECT Failed. 3706:  Syntax error: expected something between a string or a Unicode character literal and ','. 

SEL Greatest(date1,date2,date3...)
SELECT Failed. 9881:  Function 'GREATEST' called with an invalid number or type of parameters
```

How to solve this?
thx

Answer (score 2):

Yep, it's stupid, `LEAST` and `GREATEST` don't work with date/time (fixed in 16.10).

As a workaround you can cast it to integer:

```
SEL cast(GREATEST(cast(date1 as int)
                 ,cast(date2 as int)
                 ,cast(date3 as int)
                 ...) as date)
```

Hopefully there's no NULL, otherwise it gets ugly with additional COALESCEs/NULLIF

Comment: SELECT Failed. 3706:  Syntax error: expected something between ')' and ','.

Comment: @GrigoryP: I can't see what you keyed in :-) Too many brackets or in the wrong place

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation, arguments for the GREATEST function can't be *dates*. Try to convert them to *strings* in the YYYYMMDD (or similar) format (so that the result wouldn't suffer from issues when strings are being sorted).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT (
        SELECT MAX(maxdate)
        FROM (
            VALUES (date1)
                ,(date2)
                ,(date3)
            ) AS maximumdate(maxdate)
        ) AS maxdate
FROM #temp
```

Answer (score 0):

In TD 16.x0, GREATEST/LEAST work both with dates and timestamps. However users may need to add database, like it was UDF function:

```
SELECT TD_SYSFNLIB.LEAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0),ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0),2))
```

Comment: `td_sysfnlib` is in the search path, thus no need for a qualified name (unless you got another UDF with the same name in `syslib`